# Replace Text With Another Text Upon Hover Only Using HTML

Tags: html, css

i am trying to replace the text when someone hovers over the original text into a new text. is there a way i can do this in pure HTML without CSS at all? Anyways, below are my codes that i've worked out recently:

**HTML Code:**

```
<a href="#" class="button">
    <span>Product Name</span>
</a>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
.buton:not(:hover):before {
content: "Old Text";
}
.btn_action_1 span:hover:before {
content: "New Text";
}
```

I want to do the same but with HTML only. is it possible? Bz i have several different elements so it will be much easier on me. Thx

Comment: `<a href="#" class="button"><span class="default">Old Text</span><span class="hover">New Text</span></a>` and `.button:not(:hover)>.hover,.button:hover>.default {display:none}` should work.

Comment: Impossible to implement with pure HTML.

Comment: Why have you tagged the question with CSS if you don't want CSS answers? This is, as already noted, impossible with just HTML. With CSS it *might* be possible depending on where the 'new text' comes from (if it's in the page already then it's a maybe depending on the structure of the page and elements); otherwise - it it's received from a server, or from user interaction - then it's likely impossible without JavaScript. "*I want to do [this] with HTML only ... so it will be much easier on me.*" - where did you get the idea that web design should be "*easy*"?

Comment: hello @NiettheDarkAbsol Thx so much mister for solving my problem. I did exactly what you provided and everything worked smoothly. Much appreciated

Comment: my problem is solved @DavidThomas

Comment: Then please post your solution to your problem, or delete the question. If one of the current answers was the solution then please accept the most useful answer as the solution (clicking the check-mark below the up/down arrows by the 'score').

Comment: I don't see a check mark next to the post. there's only favourite. how do i mark it as Accepted?

Comment: it says I can accept my answer in 2 days. WTF?

Comment: HTML stands for Hyper Text Markup Language, which is a static markup language meant to describe semantic content. CSS is for defining the visual representation of those semantic contents, this includes styles that react to user-interaction (like hover). If you need to dynamically modify the actual semantic content, you need Javascript. The closest you can get with HTML-only is using the `title` attribute, which will display a tooltip when hovering an element, for example: `<span title="New Text">Old Text</span>`.

Comment: hey @John White. i know pretty much about what each means. But i'm not looking to learn coding right now as i'm a bit busy. Thx for the useful tips anyways.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. If you want your site to be updated without being reloaded you need to use CSS (for simple visual changes) or JavaScript (for everything more complex).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
 a:hover { font-size:0;}

 a:hover:after {
 font-size: 18px;
 content: attr(data-hover);
 }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="" data-hover="CLICK ME">HOVER </a>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the best I could do. Don't know anything about only using html to get hover effect or maybe i din't learn as of yet.Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.btn_action_1:before {
  content: "";
}

.btn_action_1:hover:before {
  content: "View Details";
}

.btn_action_1:hover span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn_action_1">
  <span>Product Name</span>
  <i class="ico_arrow"></i>
</a>
```

is this what you want?

Comment: Read the question before answering please.